# Do I need to used a Synchronized statement every time I read/write to my database?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-file, android-backup-service

I'm implementing Android Backup Service and [the guide says that](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html#Files)

> reading and writing to external storage is **not threadsafe**

It then says that the `onBackup` and `onRestore` functions should be performed in a `synchronized` statement. My question is: do I need to use this approach everywhere I read/write my database?

So

```
db.open();
course = db.getCourse(courseId);
db.close();
```

would become...

```
synchronized(MyConstants.DBContant){
    db.open();
    course = db.getCourse(courseId);
    db.close();
}
```

I read/write to my db a lot. I want to make sure before I go add this everywhere.

Comment: `SQLiteDatabase` is thread-safe, and doesn't need explicit synchronization on concurrent access.

Comment: @corsair992, Even if another service is accessing the file in a method which is not thread-safe? If the backup service tries to access the file while it's being edited, it will be blocked?

Comment: Whether it will be blocked or not depends on whether your transaction is exclusive or immediate, and whether you have write-ahead logging enabled or not - either way it would be atomic and thread-safe. Currently, the connection pool used by `SQLiteDatabase` only allows a maximum of one concurrent connection though, so it will always be blocked in the current semantics.

Comment: I don't alter the default write-ahead logging and I don't know if my transactions are exclusive or immediate. I query to read from my db and I use SQLiteDatabase's `insert` method to create new rows. But it sounds like I should be safe even if an external process is trying to read/write the database.

Comment: SQLite statements outside of an explicit transactions implicitly start a deferred transaction which will be committed after all the current reads and writes are completed. Write-ahead logging is disabled by default on AOSP, but it wouldn't make any difference in this case. Actually, SQLite's own locking mechanism seems to be based on a fail mechanism instead of wait, which is probably the reason why the Android `SQLiteDatabase` only allows one connection at a time (the rest are deferred). In the case of inter-process access, you might have to handle concurrency yourself though.